# How to use level-values for indexing in a dask dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

from a filtering step on the initial values of a data set I have a subset of indices of a much larger data set in the form

```py
indices = pandas_DataFrame_of_initial_values[my_subset].index.get_level_values(0)
```

those indices are of the form

```
Int64Index([...], dtype='int64', name='id', length=N)
```

with this, I like to use the indices to reduce the large data set using Dask, given the data set as

```py
from dask import dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.read_csv(path_to_data).set_index("id")
```

I tried

```py
ddf.loc[indices]
# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

and

```py
ddf[ddf.index.isin(indices)]
# NotImplementedError: dask.array<isin, shape=(nan,), dtype=bool, chunksize=(nan,), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
```

and

```py
ddf[ddf.index.isin(indices.compute())]
# ValueError: Item wrong length 236644 instead of 0.
```

How to actually use the subset of indices on the larger data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that the `Int64index` type has a `to_list` method and with that the selection with the `loc` property works:

```py
ddf.loc[indices.to_list()].compute()
```

Comment: Is this a working solution? If yes, you will want to accept it; if not, you might want to delete it, as others will think that the question has been answered.

Comment: Yes, its working. And yes, I've accepted it now; I couldn't before, it was still blocked for two days.
Regardless, I would happily accept another answer, if there is some more information to give to the whys and hows of indexing...